# How do I render a html page from a view returning JSON data in django?

Tags: html, json, django, python-3.x, django-views

I have a function in my views.py which returns JSON data, what I have in mind is rendering a HTML page from that data.
The same question can also be associated with data returned from rest API generic views returning JSON data.

Comment: Perhaps, you're looking to use a frontend framework like AngularJS or React, to capture the data returned and create a dynamic template.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your concern, but you can send the json data to your template using `json.dumps()`

```
response_data = {}
response_data['name'] = 'test'
response_data['message'] = 'Hi test'
render(request, "test.html", {'json_data': json.dumps(response_data)})
```

Now, you can access `json_data` in your template